# How can I insert role into code-block directive?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to insert role `:math:` (for example) into code-block directive:

```
.. code-block:: 

   :math:`2^{64} - 1`
```

but the directive does not handle this role and I get this in pdf:

[image: pdf output]

How can I insert role (math or others) into code-block directive?

Comment: A code-block renders its content as is. You cannot render a role inside a code-block.

Comment: Some roles (for example `:ref:`) are processed by the `parsed-literal` directive, but it does not work with `:math:`.

Comment: The `:math:` role works fine in a `parsed-literal` directive with Docutils. If it does not work with Sphinx, this may be a bug.

Comment: Could you please describe the desired output? Do you want block-level maths? Or a code-block with computer code (and syntax highlight) and inside it some mathematical content?